# validate .Net JWT token to call Java APIs

Tags: java, c#, .net, spring-boot, jwt

I am using Basic Authentication and JWT Token for Springboot Java APIs and that is working fine. But now I want to shift login process in another application that is created in .Net. So User can login through both applications .Net and Java and can call APIs. I am using same secret key ,Issuer,Audience,Expiry time but generated token not validated in Java.

First Exception I got

`Unsupported signature algorithm 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha256'`

**Used algorithm in both languages for Token creation**

.Net - http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha256

Java - HS256

Then I replaced the header of .Net lang generated token by  java generated token in jwt.io. After that with generated token when I hit the java api I got

`JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted` Exception

**below is my java code for Token generation**

```
 Jwts.builder()
        .setSubject(authentication.getName())
        .claim(AUTHORITIES_KEY, authorities)
        .setIssuer("")
        .setAudience("")
        .claim("uid", "")
        .claim("name", "")
        .signWith(key,SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
        .setExpiration(validity) 
  // validity = new Date((new Date()).getTime() +this.tokenValidityInMilliseconds);
        .compact();
```

below code for token validation

```
Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key).build().parseClaimsJws(authToken);
```

On .net Side

```
.setSubject(authentication.getName())
.claim(AUTHORITIES_KEY, authorities)
```

these properties are not used in payload and some other properties are also different but Issuer and Audience and expiry time is same. same Key is used for token creation. but I am unable to call java APIs with .Net generated token.

Comment: Did you find solution for this? I am also searching for a way to provide authentication in a polyglot architecture using jwt