# How to authentication for ASP.NET Core Web API 6 by JWT token generated by Spring Security (Spring Boot 2.7.0)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I have file `JwtTokenUtil.java`

```java
package com.example.multitenant.util;

import com.example.multitenant.constant.JWTConstants;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.function.Function;

@Component
public class JwtTokenUtil implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2550185165626007488L;

    public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public String getAudienceFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getAudience);
    }

    public Date getExpirationDateFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T getClaimFromToken(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(JWTConstants.SIGNING_KEY)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        final Date expiration = getExpirationDateFromToken(token);
        return expiration.before(new Date());
    }

    public String generateToken(String userName, String tenantOrClientId) {
        return doGenerateToken(userName, tenantOrClientId);
    }

    private String doGenerateToken(String subject, String tenantOrClientId) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(subject).setAudience(tenantOrClientId);
        claims.put("scopes", Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")));
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setIssuer("system")
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JWTConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS * 1000))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, JWTConstants.SIGNING_KEY)
                .compact();
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = getUsernameFromToken(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }

}
```

I have file

```java
package com.example.multitenant.security;

import com.example.multitenant.constant.JWTConstants;
import com.example.multitenant.mastertenant.config.DBContextHolder;
import com.example.multitenant.mastertenant.entity.MasterTenant;
import com.example.multitenant.mastertenant.service.MasterTenantService;
import com.example.multitenant.util.JwtTokenUtil;
import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    MasterTenantService masterTenantService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String header = httpServletRequest.getHeader(JWTConstants.HEADER_STRING);
        String username = null;
        String audience = null; //tenantOrClientId
        String authToken = null;
        if (header != null && header.startsWith(JWTConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            authToken = header.replace(JWTConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX, "");
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(authToken);
                audience = jwtTokenUtil.getAudienceFromToken(authToken);
                MasterTenant masterTenant = masterTenantService.findByClientId(Integer.valueOf(audience));
                if (null == masterTenant) {
                    logger.error("An error during getting tenant name");
                    throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid tenant and user.");
                }
                DBContextHolder.setCurrentDb(masterTenant.getDbName());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                logger.error("An error during getting username from token", ex);
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
                logger.warn("The token is expired and not valid anymore", ex);
            } catch (SignatureException ex) {
                logger.error("Authentication Failed. Username or Password not valid.", ex);
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("Couldn't find bearer string, will ignore the header");
        }
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(authToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")));
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest));
                logger.info("authenticated user " + username + ", setting security context");
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }

}
```

JWT token generate by Spring Security (for many RESTful end-points what written by Spring RESTful). Sample working token:
https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJkb25odXZ5IiwiYXVkIjoiMSIsInNjb3BlcyI6W3siYXV0aG9yaXR5IjoiUk9MRV9BRE1JTiJ9XSwiaXNzIjoic3lzdGVtIiwiaWF0IjoxNjU1MzA0NDczLCJleHAiOjE2NTUzMjI0NzN9.9X3k1VJJOp937X6LJiWuizrZyBP8nROAYlcwiKriXEE

I need call web service to generate PDF invoice from ASP.NET Core Web API 6. Of course, I need validate perimssion/security by JWT token. How to authentication for ASP.NET Core Web API 6 by JWT token generated by Spring Security (Spring Boot 2.7.0)?

I want call ASP.NET Core Web API 6 APIs (with commercial .NET component back-end) directly without call via Spring web-service (with free and open source Java component back-end).

I think this is a tough problem when interface/integration between Java Spring Boot 2.7.0 and ASP.NET Web API 6 and hope you give me a working solution.

Some thing like this [validate .Net JWT token to call Java APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68517943/validate-net-jwt-token-to-call-java-apis) but in reverse direction.

Answer (score 1):

For example I have a .net 6 api project, I installed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` package for JwtAuthentication.

In `program.cs`, I add the configuration like this, adding this configuration will make your api validate the token and check token if has correct issuer/autdience, if expired, more details can be seen in `new TokenValidationParameters` method:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = TokenHelper.Issuer,
                ValidAudience = TokenHelper.Audience,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String(TokenHelper.Secret))
            };

        });
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
...
...
...
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

And in my api controller, I added `[Authorize]` annotation so that if the input request doesn't contain request header like `Authoration: Bearer xxxxxx`, api will return 401 unauthorize:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("Hello")]
public class HelloController : ControllerBase
{
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> GetAsync()
    {
        var accessToken = await TokenHelper.GenerateAccessToken("userOne");
        return accessToken;
    }
}
```

This is the code how I generate access token which is similar with yours by Java， [follow this blog](https://codingsonata.com/apply-jwt-access-tokens-and-refresh-tokens-in-asp-net-core-web-api-6/), token are the same, na matter generated by java or .net.

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace WebApiNet6
{
    public class TokenHelper
    {
        public const string Issuer = "http://mytest.com";
        public const string Audience = "http://mytest.com";
        public const string Secret = "p0GXO6VuVZLRPef0tyO9jCqK4uZufDa6LP4n8Gj+8hQPB30f94pFiECAnPeMi5N6VT3/uscoGH7+zJrv4AuuPg==";
        public static async Task<string> GenerateAccessToken(string userId)
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Convert.FromBase64String(Secret);

            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userId)
            });

            var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = claimsIdentity,
                Issuer = Issuer,
                Audience = Audience,
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15),
                SigningCredentials = signingCredentials,

            };
            var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            return await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken));
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

without token:
[image]